# Stanford NLP regexNER on lemmas

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've been experimenting with Stanford regex NER annotator and TokensRegex. It works great, I just wonder if it's possible to do regex matching on lemmas instead of words?

For example, I create standard regex NER tsv file:

```
plane   TRANSPORT
car     TRANSPORT
...
```

Can I perhaps create a TokensRegex rule with this logic: `if current token has lemma which has a match in TRANSPORT class, mark it as TRANSPORT`.

The goal is to also label `planes`, `cars` etc. as TRANSPORT without having to specify all these variations in the tsv file.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.tokensregex.rules basic-ner.rules -file lemma-example.txt -outputFormat text
```

basic-ner.rules

```
# these Java classes will be used by the rules
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

$TRANSPORT_TYPES = "/car|plane/"

# rule for recognizing transport
{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ([{lemma:$TRANSPORT_TYPES}]), action: Annotate($0, ner, "TRANSPORT"), result: "TRANSPORT" }
```

More info on NER and TokensRegex here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was hoping I could replace `$TRANSPORT_TYPES = "/car|plane/"` with `$TRANSPORT_TYPES = ( [ { ner:AERIAL_VEHICLE } ] )`, but that gives class cast exception `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequencePattern cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. But that's fine, I can transform my data to rules. I just wonder if there's a way to specify priority over other classes in TokenRegex syntax? I mean to mimic this: `xxx\tRULE_LOCATION\tLOCATION,LOCATION_CUSTOM\t2.0`